# Group by on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have an application table, each application can have activities, each time an activity is updated there is a log in the activityupdate table.

activityupdate table:
- id
- activity_id
- user_id
- date

activity table:
- id
- application_id
- rank
- ...

I'd like to get the last activityupdate for all activities of an application order by activity rank

I have

```
SELECT au
FROM activityupdate au
INNER JOIN activity ac
ON au.activity_id = ac.id
INNER JOIN application ap
ON ac.application_id = ap.id
WHERE ap.id = 3
GROUP BY au, ac.rank
ORDER BY ac.rank ASC
```

But this doesn't works, I don't know why I have to set au and ac.rank in the GROUP BY

Thanks for your help

Edit, 
thanks Gordon, I find the solution

```
select *
from (SELECT au,
      row_number() over (partition by au.activity_id order by au.date desc) as seqnum
      FROM activityupdate au INNER JOIN
      activity ac
      ON au.activity_id = ac.id INNER JOIN
      application ap
      ON ac.application_id = ap.id
  WHERE ap.id = 3
  ORDER BY ac.rank ASC
 ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: what about the aggregate? you didn't include it in your `SELECT`

Comment: I'm not very good on SQL but the aggregate return only one result no ? I'd like to get the last activityupdate for all activities of an application order by activity rank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an aggregation.  The function `row_number()` does what you need.  It assigns a sequential number to rows within a group (defined by the `partition by` clause).  The order of the numbers is determined by the `order by`.

You can then choose the most recent using a `where` clause:

```
select *
from (SELECT au,
             row_number() over (partition by au order by rank desc) as seqnum
      FROM activityupdate au INNER JOIN
           activity ac
           ON au.activity_id = ac.id INNER JOIN
           application ap
           ON ac.application_id = ap.id
      WHERE ap.id = 3
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```